# Python mode function gives error for real-valued vector: No unique mode; found 2 equally common values

Tags: python, numpy, random, statistics, probability-distribution

Why can't `statistics.mode` find the mode for a normally distributed (therefore, unimodal) random variable, but works fine for vectors containing integers?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand,randn
import statistics as st

y = randn(20)
print(st.mode(y))
```

This returns the following error

```
StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 20 equally common values
```

Comment: Could you provide the code that produces an error/doesn't produce the desired result?

Comment: it is what's given. the error comes up for every generated `y`

Answer (score 1):

That's because mode doesn't exist. The number of unique element in y and the total element in y are same so no mode exits by definition.

```
np.size(np.unique(y)) - np.size(y)

>>> 0
```

Mode doesn't exist can also be verified by looking at the histogram (flat in the present case). Peaks in this graph represents mode and since we cann't find a peak, mode is None.

[image: Histogram for y]

Edit: If you want to really find the mode then

1. Draw enough samples from the distribution. So that it reflects the original pdf
2. Adjust the precision (I have rounded it off to 1 decimal place). Consequently, the model will have a error range accordingly.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand,randn
import statistics as st

y = randn(10000000)
st.mode(list(np.round(y,1)))
```

This gives

```
>>> 0.0
```

Following is the hist (See now you also get a peak at 0.0)
[image: Hist for large samples]

Comment: A normal distribution always has a mode though so the program is wrong obviously, even the histogram. what is the work around

Comment: The output of the ```statistics ``` library is 100% correct. You cann't compute the mode in your case.

Comment: Although, you are sampling from a normal distribution but the sample size matters! The present sample size is not a representation of the normal distribtion but rather a uniform distribution. And thats exactly why you are getting the error by the ```statistics```

Comment: Check out the edit @develarist, this will solve your problem.

Comment: I've raised the sample size to 2000000 before and the error is still there

Comment: Can you please copy the code I provided and then run it. Its working fine

Comment: what is the `round` for, and what if it is not included

Comment: Can you pls change the decimal places for rounding off ranging from 1 to say 6. For each setting observe the peak in the histogram. Also calculate mode for each. you will then understand its purpose.

Comment: Actually, the pdf will gradually change from normal to uniform. round provides the precision of number measurement.

Answer (score 1):

`randn` returns a third-party `ndarray` rather than a Python builtin array (i.e. a `list`). The `statistics` module was not built to serve numpy explicitly and so unexpected behaviour occurs.

A solution could be converting `y` to a `list` (i.e. `st.mode(list(y))`).

Comment: Completly disagree with the reasoning!!

Comment: @Ragnar Ah so when I reproduced OP's example, I got a number which wasn't even in `y`, and so thought that was their problem (and converting to `list` solved it). If it's something else then ignore me.

Comment: Ragnar updated his answer using your `list` idea though

Comment: Dunno what Ragnar is up to, but try running your example and change the last line i.e.
`print(st.mode(y))` -> `print(list(st.mode(y)))`.

Also note that `y` will not have a mode or mean of exactly `0`, as it is just generating numbers that will have modes or means that _tend towards_ `0`.

Comment: I don't understand why someone would say your idea doesn't work and takes it for their own

Comment: Ragnars example isn't doing what I suggest (why `round` or change the sample size).

Comment: @develarist Ah so what's the specific problem? Ragnar edited your question to say you get a `StatisticsError` raised—is that true? If so I can't help, because I can't reproduce that problem. I tried this on Python3.8.

Comment: the error was also in the question title. i have the same python. why don't you get the error

Comment: @develarist Hmm, could you print the output of `y`?

Comment: `y` is a random number generator, so it's stochastic

Comment: @develarist That's the thing, I'm guessing something is wrong with your Python environment so that the "OS-level RNG" being used by `randn` is faulty.. Just `print(y)` to see the contents of `y`. If you mean there's a different value for `y` everytime, then yeah I know that should be the case.